# Error while running npm start in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created a react project using `npx`

```
npx create-react-app react-authentication
```

After that when I run

```
npm start
```

It throws an error saying:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:456
      throw e;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/astraCreateDataProperty/react-authentication/node_modules/es-abstract/2020/CreateDataProperty.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:922:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/astra*/react-authentication/node_modules/object.getownpropertydescriptors/implementation.js:3:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/home/astra*/react-authentication/node_modules/es-abstract/package.json'
}
```

I tried some methods to solve this like

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json`
3. `npm cache clean --force`
4. `npm install`

But still, the same error persists. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Did you move into the directory that holds your package.json?

Comment: I didn't get you @tim

Comment: When you use create react app it makes a folder that holds your project. You need to go into that folder then npm run start

Comment: I am doing that... but still I am getting that error